# Vector analysis : following given trajectory, will particles collide?

Tags: vector-analysis

Let two particles move by a trajectory respectively given by $\vec{r_1}(t)=t\vec{i}+t^2\vec{j}+t^3\vec{k}$ and $\vec{r_2}(t)=(1+2t)\vec{i}+(1+6t)\vec{j}+(1+14t)\vec{k}$.

In my vector analysis course, I need to determine if particles will collide. I guess that I need to solve the following system of equations :
\begin{cases}
t=1+2t \\ 
t^2=1+6t \\ 
t^3=1+14t
\end{cases}
Which has no solution, right? Is that so simple?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is true
if the particles have
the same $t$.
But, 
if you are just interested
in whether or not
the two *trajectories* intersect,
you want different
parameters.

In the latter case,
you want to see if
there is a solution to
$r_1(s) = r_2(t)$,
or,
looking at the components,

$\begin{array}\\
s = 1+2t\\
s^2 = 1+6t\\
s^3 = 1+14t\\
\end{array}
$

For this,
$t = (s-1)/2$,
so
$s^2
=1+6((s-1)/2)
=1+3(s-1)
=3s-2
$,
or
$s^2-3s+2
= 0
$.
This has solutions
$s = 2$ and $s = 1$.

From the third coordinate,
$s^3
=1+14((s-1)/2)
=1 + 7(s-1)
= 7s-6
$.
Of the two possible values
for $s$,
only $s=1$ works.
For this,
$t = 0$.

Therefore,
the two trajectories intersect
for
$r_1(1)$
and $r_2(0)$.

Looking at the three equations,
this becomes obvious,
but that's math biz.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is really that simple.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1:

The *time* to collision is same, is quotient of relative distance and relative velocity.

Time =

$$ \dfrac{r_2 - r_1}{ \dot{r_2} -\dot{r_1} }= \dfrac{r_2 }{ \dot{r_2}  }=  \dfrac{ r_1}{ \dot{r_1} }  $$

Comment: I don't understand why the velocities of the particles are relevant here. Could you clarify?

Comment: No motion, no collision.

Comment: If the particles are stationary and in different places, the equations the OP wrote won't have a solution. There's no need to consider the particles' velocities explicitly. Moreover, if there is a collision, the condition $\dot{r}_1(t) = \dot{r}_2(t)$ will not always be satisfied when the particles collide, so I don't understand why you wrote that condition down.

Comment: Apologies, expressed incorrectly what I wished to say, editing it...